# Can't add fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to add a input by pressing the addextra button nothing appears. I have probably made a silly mistake somewhere but can't seem to find one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="addextra" name="addextra"> + </button>
  <div id="ip_div">

  </div>
  <br>
</body>
<script>
    var fieldNum = 0; 
        $("#addextra").click(function() { 
        var newInput = $("<input></input>") 
            .attr("id", "extra-" + fieldNum) 
            .attr("name", "extra-" + fieldNum) 
        $("#ip_div").append(newInput); 
        fieldNum++; 
        });
</script> 
</html>
```

Python

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add():
    return render_template('add.html', Name=User.Name)
```

Comment: Is that ALL of your code?  Because nowhere in here are you loading jquery.  The "$" function is not built-in to Javascript -- that's jquery, and you have to load it.

Comment: Thanks I didn’t know that was a seperate thing :)